# the fastest and low server method to set an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "data.php"
}).done(function(data) { 
    //code
});
```

1. which is the fastest and low server  method to set an AJAX call only when there is new data into the "data.php" file ? ex. setInterval
2. how to check when this request is complete and not to send another req. when the old one is n't complete ?
3. show a "loading..." status when the ajax request is proccessing?

Comment: What do you mean by "fastest and low server method"?  For checking when the request is complete, that's what the `.done()` function is for.  That will be called when the request is complete.  To show a status, just display some element before calling this and then hide that element in the `.done()` function.

Comment: check the api: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/, use "success" method to hide the loader, show loader before the ajax function, change some global variable to prevent sending another request and check it each time before you do

Comment: Your best bets are long polling or WebSockets.

Comment: Not sure about the fastest method but in the code example you've shown you've answered your second question with the `.done` function. Set code in there to determine that the request has completed and what ever you need to stop it from re-occurring. As for the Loading message, have a hidden div on the page and show it before the ajax call and then hide it again in the `.done` function.

Comment: thanks but how to set an refresh interval to this function only whene there is nw data in "data.php" i mean new data in mysql_database

Comment: `only when there is new data into the "data.php" file ? ex. setInterval`  JasonP suggested WebSockets or long polling, which are both correct.  You could also use setInterval (as you mention) to check whether there is new data and only get it when there is.  Show us the code you have already tried and we can help with your problems with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var inProcess = 0;
function get_new_stuff() {
    if (inProcess == 0) {
        inProcess = 1;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', //or GET
            dataType: "json", //or html, text
            url: 'data.php',
            data: '',
            beforeSend: function() {
                // please wait... message
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // returned data
                inProcess = 0;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // on error
                inProcess = 0;
                alert(textStatus + ": " + errorThrown);
            },
            cache: false
        });
    }
}

setTimeout(get_new_stuff, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: `inProcess` is not being reset in `success` callback.  Also, this just gets data every 10 seconds, rather than only get new data when there is some, which is what he asked for :)